# Connect database in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Since i am new to **Angular2**, Can you please give me the solution that how to connect Oracle database using **Angular 2**.

I have tried using Meteor, But in that we are able to connect with MongoDB only, but my need is to connect with Oracle 10G database.

Am using Webstorm IDE for Developing application, Please help me guys..

Comment: Can you be a little more precise. Do you have a server communicating with the database, and how is server - client communication handled?

Comment: Not able to connect with Database Server itself Sir.

Comment: checkout [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) with [sails oracle adapter](https://github.com/atiertant/sails-oracle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just been having the same issue and I think the problem that you are having is the lack of a back-end with some API (for example REST-API).

This back-end will make sure to translate your HTTP requests from your Angular 2 App into prepared SQL-Statements and execute them to retrieve the data from your Database.

You should then parse the retrieved data into JSON-Format and send the response to your Angular 2 front-end.
[Access DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAK8s.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can not connect database to Angular 2 directly as Angular 2 is a Client-side language.

You can build a RESTful service (API) that handles read/write requests with your database using a server-side language (e.g. PHP, ASP .net, NodeJS, Ruby on Rails,….).